# How to correctly use mkl_domatcopy from MKL?

Tags: fortran, intel-mkl

I need to find a faster way to transpose a matrix using MKL. And I tried mkl_domatcopy from MKL but never get it right.

Here is the test code(Fortran):

```
        PROGRAM MAIN

                INTEGER, PARAMETER:: NROW = 3 !rows
                INTEGER, PARAMETER:: NCOL = 3 !cols

                REAL*8, ALLOCATABLE:: M(:,:)
                REAL*8, ALLOCATABLE:: MT(:,:)

                INTEGER:: i,j

                ALLOCATE(M(NROW,NCOL))
                ALLOCATE(MT(NROW,NCOL))


                DO i = 1, NROW
                DO j = 1, NCOL
                        M(i,j)=i
                END DO
                END DO

call mkl_domatcopy("c","t",3,3,9,M,3,MT,3)

                print *,M
                print *,"************************"
                print *,MT

        END
```

And the output is:

```
   1.00000000000000        2.00000000000000        3.00000000000000
   1.00000000000000        2.00000000000000        3.00000000000000
   1.00000000000000        2.00000000000000        3.00000000000000
 ************************
           0
```

why the MT is 0?Is it beacause I use it wrong or something?

Documents about this function:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/520863

PS:I still don't get what 'alpha' means.

Comment: Is this fixed or free formatted code. I case of fixed formatted code at what 'position does the 'call'  start looks like position 1, move it to, at least,position 6.

Comment: Assuming (as in the comment above) that really is a subroutine call not a comment, don't you have some means (module, include file, etc.) of specifying the (explicit) interface for the subroutine?

Comment: It's fixed formatted code. I am sorry that I don't get 'position 1'.Does it mean that i should move the 'call' to the bottom ?

Comment: Indent the `call` line so that the `c` is in (at least) column 7, but keeping the line in the same place.  Aligned with the other parts of the code would be nice.

Comment: The 'call' line is not a comment.I delete the space before 'call' just because i don't want to use '&'.Sorry about that.The function called comes from intel MKL.It's OK adding '-mkl' option when compiling.

Comment: The behaviour you are seeing suggests to me that you aren't providing the arguments to the subroutine as the type that it is expecting.  In particular, I'd expect one of them to be real rather than integer.  You want to carefully check the subroutine call, preferably by finding a way to get the compiler to do it.

Comment: The manual (Fortran version) is here https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/468656 Please also try inserting `include "mkl.fi"` or `include "mkl_trans.fi"` just below the PROGRAM statement, which likely gives useful messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As user roygvib suggests in the comments, by including the `mkl.fi` file would give you additional details.

This code

```
    PROGRAM MAIN

            INCLUDE 'mkl.fi'

            INTEGER, PARAMETER:: NROW = 3 !rows
            INTEGER, PARAMETER:: NCOL = 3 !cols

            REAL*8, ALLOCATABLE:: M(:,:)
            REAL*8, ALLOCATABLE:: MT(:,:)
            INTEGER:: i,j

            ALLOCATE(M(NROW,NCOL))
            ALLOCATE(MT(NROW,NCOL))

            DO i = 1, NROW
            DO j = 1, NCOL
                    M(i,j)=i
            END DO
            END DO

            call mkl_domatcopy("c","t",3,3,9,M,3,MT,3)

            print *,M
            print *,"************************"
            print *,MT

    END
```

raises the following error

> test.f90(23): error #6633: The type of the actual argument differs
>   from the type of the dummy argument.   [9]
>                   call mkl_domatcopy("c","t",3,3,9,M,3,MT,3)
>   -----------------------------------------------^ compilation aborted for test.f90 (code 1)

Interestingly, if you turn that `9` into a double precision value (or variable) -- note that here I simply appended the `d0` suffix to the floating point value.

```
    PROGRAM MAIN

            INCLUDE 'mkl.fi'

            INTEGER, PARAMETER:: NROW = 3 !rows
            INTEGER, PARAMETER:: NCOL = 3 !cols

            REAL*8, ALLOCATABLE:: M(:,:)
            REAL*8, ALLOCATABLE:: MT(:,:)
            INTEGER:: i,j

            ALLOCATE(M(NROW,NCOL))
            ALLOCATE(MT(NROW,NCOL))

            DO i = 1, NROW
            DO j = 1, NCOL
                    M(i,j)=i
            END DO
            END DO

            call mkl_domatcopy("c","t",3,3,9d0,M,3,MT,3)

            print *,M
            print *,"************************"
            print *,MT

    END
```

then your application returns

```
$ ./test
1.00000000000000        2.00000000000000        3.00000000000000
1.00000000000000        2.00000000000000        3.00000000000000
1.00000000000000        2.00000000000000        3.00000000000000
************************
9.00000000000000        9.00000000000000        9.00000000000000
18.0000000000000        18.0000000000000        18.0000000000000
27.0000000000000        27.0000000000000        27.0000000000000
```

Finally, with respect to what `alpha` means, the [manual](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/468656) says

> *alpha* This parameter scales the input matrix by alpha.

and notice that the output is the tranposed and each element multiplied by 9.

Comment: Thanks.I immediately know how the function works after seeing your example.And I have tested what user roygvib suggests and it did work.

Answer (score -1):

The fastest way to do a transpose in fortran90 is as follows

```
B = TRANSPOSE(A)
```

And the fastest way to do a MATMUL is:

```
C = MATMUL(A,B)
```

As it is inherent in the language, I am not sure where MKL/IMKL comes into play?

Comment: The fact that it is inherent in the language, does not mean that it is the fastest implementation. While `MATMUL` can be better than MKL for small matrices (especially if MKL is not configured properly), for many architectures MKL usually is faster for larger matrices.